# Am I poisoned forever?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

I needed the talisman o'namsilat, so I went into the Copperhead Club. This got me poisoned with the Ancient Annoying Serpent Poison. I've gotten what I wanted through other means, so I didn't end up doing what Shen Copperhead wanted.

Am I stuck being poisoned forever, or is there another way to remove this, without having to go through and do what Shen wants?

Comment: Remember, never trust serpents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The poison will be cleared if you ascend, otherwise you need to complete Shen's quest.

It's also exactly what it says, annoying. It shouldn't hamper you from doing other things while you are under its effects.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't prevent anything (just the small stat loss), but it just bugs me that it's there!

Comment: @AshleyNunn yep the annoyance is both an in game and out of game effect

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, as it is an intrinsic effect, there is no way to remove it outside of completing Shen's quest.